# Issues connecting via ssh to raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, ssh, boot-issues

I have had my pi set up for quite some time now. All of a sudden I started having issues connecting via SSH, getting a connection refused. When I boot up when connected the a screen I get stuck on this screen. Also I do see the pi on the network, just not sure why I can no longer SSH into it.

[image]

Comment: Can you reach command terminal of Pi with a monitor and keyboard or is it unreachebla in any way?

Comment: The last line you see in that image is all I get to. I can type stuff in but it doesn't do anything, just starts a new line when I press return.

Comment: Can you try holding shift key for recovery as explained here : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the reason that you cannot ssh into your pi is that you are hanging on boot. The boot process is hanging before it starts SSH. My *guess* based on the info you provided is that you may have a power issue. To test that theory, take all the usb devices away, including the wifi and the logitech stuff. If the boot works, then add them back one by one. Keep the monitor connected and look for a rainbow icon in the upper right. If you see that, you have a power issue.

If you are still hanging on boot then it's possible that your SD card is corrupted, or at the very least there is something in your boot sequence that is causing an issue. This can happen if you have power issues. It looks like you are at least running a wifi usb dongle and a wireless keyboard or mouse, so if you have a poor power supply you could get intermittent failures. Either way, the path of least resistance would be to re-image the SD card. Then boot up the newly imaged SD card with all USB stuff connected + the monitor and look for the rainbow icon in the upper right which tells you there is a power issue.

If none of this works then just ignore this answer, I'm out of ideas based just on the info your provided.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up using a new sd card

Comment: Make sure to test for power issues like I suggested. Power issues can cause your ad card to become corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

At the terminal, type in: tasksel-->
This will bring you to the Package Configuration Menu-->
8th choice-->
select SSH Server

Comment: there is not prompt to enter anything on this screen